# Bootstrap: Prepended input: outline around prepended element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a prepended input like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/swQa4/

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
</div>
```

How can i achieve, that the blue outline (showing when focused) goes around the prepended symbol?

Edit: Similar to the search field at github repos (e.g. https://github.com/cloudera/repository-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the solution found by Ben Swinburne so that it works with prepended and appended fields:

http://jsfiddle.net/WBJ6H/

```
<div class="input-prepend input-append input-prepend-inner">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
    <button class="btn" type="button">Copy</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-prepend-inner .add-on
{
    /* Move the add-on above the input element */
    position: absolute;

    /* The focus brings the input to z-index 2, so needs to be higher */
    z-index: 3;
}

.input-prepend-inner input[type=text]
{
    /* Move the text in the input out from under the add-on */
    padding-left: 32px;

    /* Re apply the border radius which we've made look ugly with the add-on on top.
       The styling is applied specifically to top-left / bottom-left
       to allow .input-append to overwrite the right border-radius side. */
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.input-prepend-inner .add-on
{
    /* Remove the border, input now takes care of this except from the right one */
    border: 0;

    /* Reseparate the add-on from the input */
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);

    /* Account for the 1px gap caused by removing the border */
    margin: 1px 0 1px 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The input element is that which has the `:focus` pseudo selector attached so the easiest way to get it around everything is to extend the input element to the size which you want the blue aura to show.

What this means is that you'll have to position the `.add-on` on top of the input element.

Here's a crude example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KUGJq/) which might interfere with Bootstrap slightly more than you'd like but obviously the CSS can be refined to avoid this.

All I've done is add the following

```
.input-prepend .add-on{
    /* Move the add-on above the input element */
    position:absolute;

    /* The focus brings the input to z-index 2, so needs to be higher */
    z-index:3;
}

.input-prepend input {
    /* Move the text in the input out from under the add-on */
    padding-left:32px;

    /* Re apply the border radius which we've made look ugly with the add-on on top */
    border-radius:4px;
}

.input-append .add-on, .input-prepend .add-on {
    /* Remove the border, input now takes care of this except from the right one */
    border:0;

    /* Reseparate the add-on from the input */
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;

    /* Account for the 1px gap caused by removing the border */
    margin:1px 0 1px 1px;
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution! I modified it to work with appended fields.

Answer (score 1):

### Allows Click on Icon for Input

[This fiddle has been tested in IE9+ (should work lower), FF, and Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/swQa4/13/). Unlike the `z-index` solution of some other answers here, it allows for the icon to be clicked for input to occur. It is actually quite simple in how it works.

```
.input-prepend {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: white;
}
.input-prepend .add-on {
    margin-right: -28px;
}

.input-prepend input {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: none;
    padding-left: 34px; /*28 for icon, 6 for normal padding*/
}
```

### Explanation

The icon's negative right margin causes the `input` to overlap it. The input has been given all the `border-radius` again, but it's `background` is set to `none` so that the icon can be seen. Additional right padding is added to `input` to accommodate the icon. Finally, the wrapper is given `border-radius` as well and the final `background` color is applied to the wrapper so that the `input` will still have it's white background against some other background colored container (as the fiddle illustrated).

**Update: If you don't want the inset shadow on the icon**

[This is the most cross browser friendly way I could find to hide the inset shadow you mentioned in your comment](http://jsfiddle.net/swQa4/22/). Some browsers will not honor `pointer-events` and therefore a small part of the icon area will not be recognized for trigger of input.

```
.input-prepend:before,
.input-prepend:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 0; 
    border: 2px solid #eee; /* match icon background */
    border-width: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events: none; /* for those browsers that honor */
}
.input-prepend:before {
    width: 4px;
    height: 24px;
    top: 4px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
}
```

Comment: This works, but the input's inset shadow is shown above the add-on.

Comment: Personally, I don't mind the look with the inset shadow on it. However, if that concerns you, then I posted a workaround to "hide" it while still keeping the icon (in most cases) triggering the input field to gain focus. Note that using the `z-index` solution with `pointer-events: none` on the `.add-on` will also allow focus of the input through the icon, but _only on browsers that support that property_.